# R: plotly time series graphs

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, plotly, data-visualization

I am using the R programming language. I found some examples on the plotly r website that I am trying to replicate: https://plotly.com/r/cumulative-animations/ and https://plotly.com/r/custom-buttons/

I created some artificial time series data:

```
library(xts)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

#create data

#time series 1
date_decision_made = seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")

date_decision_made <- format(as.Date(date_decision_made), "%Y/%m/%d")

property_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,100,10)

final_data <- data.frame(date_decision_made, property_damages_in_dollars)

final_data %>%
  mutate(date_decision_made = as.Date(date_decision_made)) %>%
  add_count(week = format(date_decision_made, "%W-%y"))

final_data$class = "time_series_1"


#time series 2
date_decision_made = seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")

date_decision_made <- format(as.Date(date_decision_made), "%Y/%m/%d")

property_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,10,10)

final_data_2 <- data.frame(date_decision_made, property_damages_in_dollars)

final_data_2 %>%
  mutate(date_decision_made = as.Date(date_decision_made)) %>%
  add_count(week = format(date_decision_made, "%W-%y"))

final_data_2$class = "time_series_2"

#combine
data = rbind(final_data, final_data_2)
```

I tried to follow the examples as close as I could with my data but I got the following errors:

```
#example 1


#animation

fig <- data %>%
    plot_ly(
        x = ~date_decision_made, 
        y = ~property_damages_in_dollars,
        split = ~class,
        frame = ~frame, 
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines', 
        line = list(simplyfy = F)
    )
fig <- fig %>% layout(
    xaxis = list(
        title = "Date",
        zeroline = F
    ),
    yaxis = list(
        title = "Median",
        zeroline = F
    )
) 
fig <- fig %>% animation_opts(
    frame = 100, 
    transition = 0, 
    redraw = FALSE
)
fig <- fig %>% animation_slider(
    hide = T
)
fig <- fig %>% animation_button(
    x = 1, xanchor = "right", y = 0, yanchor = "bottom"
)


   #Error in tr[["frame"]][[1]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

And the second example:

```
#example 2:

# updatemenus component
updatemenus <- list(
    list(
        active = -1,
        type= 'buttons',
        buttons = list(
            list(
                label = "time_series_1",
                method = "update",
                args = list(list(visible = c(FALSE, TRUE)),
                            list(title = "series 1",
                                 annotations = list(c(), high_annotations)))),
            list(
                label = "time_series_2",
                method = "update",
                args = list(list(visible = c(TRUE, FALSE)),
                            list(title = "series 2",
                                 annotations = list(low_annotations, c() )))),
            
        )
    )
    
    fig <- data %>% plot_ly(type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') 
    fig <- fig %>% add_lines(x=~date_decision_made, y=~property_damages_in_dollars, name="High",
                             line=list(color="#33CFA5")) 
    fig <- fig %>% add_lines(x=~date_decision_made, y=~property_damage_in_dollars, name="Low",
                             line=list(color="#F06A6A")) 
    fig <- fig %>% layout(title = "Apple", showlegend=FALSE,
                          xaxis=list(title="Date"),
                          yaxis=list(title="Price ($)"),
                          updatemenus=updatemenus)
    
    
 

       fig
    
    # Error: unexpected symbol in:
    "    
        fig"
```

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you using your function `accumulate_by` after you define it?

Comment: Thank  you for your reply! I took a second look, it seems like the accumulate_by() function is not being used?

Comment: Yep exactly. You've defined it but never used it. Further down, you try to use a variable which I would expect to have been processed by the function before being used, so I suspect that might be part of the problem.

Comment: thank you, i will try to fix it. do you see any other errors?

Comment: Can't really tell till that function is applied.

Comment: do you mean "accumulate_by"()?

Comment: Yeah, thats what I mean.

Comment: thank you - I just removed this function

Answer (score 1):

For the first example, as the first link you share in the dataset they have `frame` column which used by `frame` param in `plotly` function to create the animation.

The dataset you created didn't have `frame` variable but you still using `frame` in `plotly` call which caused the error you got.

And `frame` variable is generated using the `accumulate_by` function defined in the example link. For every date frame record, there are duplicate records of all the date before that date. So if your data has `1,462` records then the data that built for animation on plotly that created by `accumulate_by` function has `535,092` records

Here is the working code for the first example:

**[Updated] - Change x Axis to decimal number where date is decimal point.**

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(date_decision_made = as.Date(date_decision_made, format = "%Y/%m/%d"),
         tmp_date = lubridate::year(date_decision_made) + 
                    as.numeric(strftime(date_decision_made, format = "%j"))/365)

accumulate_by <- function(dat, var) {
  var <- lazyeval::f_eval(var, dat)
  lvls <- plotly:::getLevels(var)
  dats <- lapply(seq_along(lvls), function(x) {
    cbind(dat[var %in% lvls[seq(1, x)], ], frame = lvls[[x]])
  })
  dplyr::bind_rows(dats)
}



#animation
data <- data %>% accumulate_by(~tmp_date)
fig <- data %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~tmp_date, 
    y = ~property_damages_in_dollars,
    split = ~class,
    frame = ~frame, 
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'lines', 
    line = list(simplyfy = F)
  )

fig
```

Regard the code in example 2 you missed one close `)`. This mistake made everything after the assignment of `updatemenus` was included in the `list` function and end up result the error you got.

```
updatemenus <- list(
  list(
    active = -1,
    type= 'buttons',
    buttons = list(
      list(
        label = "time_series_1",
        method = "update",
        args = list(list(visible = c(FALSE, TRUE)),
                    list(title = "series 1",
                         annotations = list(c(), high_annotations)))),
      list(
        label = "time_series_2",
        method = "update",
        args = list(list(visible = c(TRUE, FALSE)),
                    list(title = "series 2",
                         annotations = list(low_annotations, c() )))),
      
    )
  )
# you missed this one
)

fig <- data %>% plot_ly(type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') 
fig <- fig %>% add_lines(x=~date_decision_made,
  y=~property_damages_in_dollars, name="High",
  line=list(color="#33CFA5")) 
fig <- fig %>% add_lines(x=~date_decision_made, 
  y=~property_damage_in_dollars, name="Low",
  line=list(color="#F06A6A")) 
fig <- fig %>% layout(title = "Apple", showlegend=FALSE,
                      xaxis=list(title="Date"),
                      yaxis=list(title="Price ($)"),
                      updatemenus=updatemenus)




fig
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! I am running the code right now, for some reason it's taking a really long time to run :)

Comment: regarding the second example, when i ran you code, it tells me "Error: object 'high_annotations' not found". do you know why this is? thank you for all your help! i really appreciate it

Comment: (i posted a related question over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65533804/r-language-code-taking-a-long-time-to-run )

Comment: I noticed that the date is in a strange format (https://imgur.com/a/uGhhuvS). Can I remove the following line of code "data <- data %>%
 mutate(tmp_date = as.numeric(as.Date(date_decision_made, format = "%Y/%m/%d")))" and then replace every "tmp_date" with "date_decision_made" instead?

Comment: @stats555 - I update the answer to decimal number with day of year are decimal points so that the X-Axis will display at 2014, 2015 which is look like year instead of previously. Note that plotly animation work well with X-Axis is number, when it not number it seem not work well...

Comment: thank you so much for your help!  When I copy/paste the updated code for Part 2 still has two errors: Error: object 'high_annotations' not found "and" Error in layout.plotly(., title = "Apple", showlegend = FALSE, xaxis = list(title = "Date"),  : 
  object 'updatemenus' not found "and" Error in eval(expr, data, expr_env) : 
  object 'property_damage_in_dollars' not found .... are all these errors to be expected?

Comment: (for part 2, I tried removing the "high_annotations" part of the code but it still doesnt run)

Comment: You can't just copy a script and run - I couldn't run the code myself as there are quite a few variables that was used but not defined in the code. I spotted the grammar error in the code as it missed `)` but there are a lot to go there. `'high_annotations' not found` is due to there is no definition... please go back to where you copy the code from and read it thoroughly