# R Language: Code Taking a Long Time to Run

Tags: r, time, time-series, plotly, data-visualization

I posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65527613/r-plotly-time-series-graphs/65529304#65529304) on how to plot interactive time series in R using the "plotly" library. I received an answer and tried running the code - however, this code has been running for the past 3 hours. The data is not that big, and I tried a similar example from the plotly website ( https://plotly.com/r/cumulative-animations/ and https://plotly.com/r/custom-buttons/) and they seem to have run fine.

Here is the code (from my previous answer) that I am trying to run:

```
#load libraries and generate artificial time series data (this part works)

library(xts)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

#create data

#time series 1
date_decision_made = seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")

date_decision_made <- format(as.Date(date_decision_made), "%Y/%m/%d")

property_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,100,10)

final_data <- data.frame(date_decision_made, property_damages_in_dollars)

final_data %>%
  mutate(date_decision_made = as.Date(date_decision_made)) %>%
  add_count(week = format(date_decision_made, "%W-%y"))

final_data$class = "time_series_1"


#time series 2
date_decision_made = seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")

date_decision_made <- format(as.Date(date_decision_made), "%Y/%m/%d")

property_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,10,10)

final_data_2 <- data.frame(date_decision_made, property_damages_in_dollars)

final_data_2 %>%
  mutate(date_decision_made = as.Date(date_decision_made)) %>%
  add_count(week = format(date_decision_made, "%W-%y"))

final_data_2$class = "time_series_2"

#combine
data = rbind(final_data, final_data_2)
```

Part 1:

```
#part 1:

data <- data %>%
 mutate(tmp_date = as.numeric(as.Date(date_decision_made, format = "%Y/%m/%d")))

accumulate_by <- function(dat, var) {
  var <- lazyeval::f_eval(var, dat)
  lvls <- plotly:::getLevels(var)
  dats <- lapply(seq_along(lvls), function(x) {
    cbind(dat[var %in% lvls[seq(1, x)], ], frame = lvls[[x]])
  })
  dplyr::bind_rows(dats)
}
data <- data %>% accumulate_by(~tmp_date)

fig <- data %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~tmp_date, 
    y = ~property_damages_in_dollars,
    split = ~class,
    frame = ~frame, 
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'lines', 
    line = list(simplyfy = F)
  )

fig
```

Part 2:

```
#part 2

updatemenus <- list(
  list(
    active = -1,
    type= 'buttons',
    buttons = list(
      list(
        label = "time_series_1",
        method = "update",
        args = list(list(visible = c(FALSE, TRUE)),
                    list(title = "series 1",
                         annotations = list(c(), high_annotations)))),
      list(
        label = "time_series_2",
        method = "update",
        args = list(list(visible = c(TRUE, FALSE)),
                    list(title = "series 2",
                         annotations = list(low_annotations, c() )))),
      
    )
  )

)

fig <- data %>% plot_ly(type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') 
fig <- fig %>% add_lines(x=~date_decision_made,
  y=~property_damages_in_dollars, name="High",
  line=list(color="#33CFA5")) 
fig <- fig %>% add_lines(x=~date_decision_made, 
  y=~property_damage_in_dollars, name="Low",
  line=list(color="#F06A6A")) 
fig <- fig %>% layout(title = "Apple", showlegend=FALSE,
                      xaxis=list(title="Date"),
                      yaxis=list(title="Price ($)"),
                      updatemenus=updatemenus)




fig
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Or is there an issue with my computer and R console? The data is not that big and I have run similar procedures on data of similar size in the past without too much trouble.

Thanks

NOTE: session info

```
 sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plotly_4.9.2.1 dplyr_1.0.2    ggplot2_3.3.2  xts_0.12.1     zoo_1.8-8     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tinytex_0.26         tidyselect_1.1.0     xfun_0.15            purrr_0.3.4          reshape2_1.4.4       splines_4.0.2       
 [7] lattice_0.20-41      colorspace_1.4-1     vctrs_0.3.2          generics_0.0.2       viridisLite_0.3.0    htmltools_0.5.0     
[13] stats4_4.0.2         yaml_2.2.1           survival_3.2-7       prodlim_2019.11.13   rlang_0.4.7          ModelMetrics_1.2.2.2
[19] pillar_1.4.6         glue_1.4.1           withr_2.3.0          xgboost_1.1.1.1      foreach_1.5.1        lifecycle_0.2.0     
[25] plyr_1.8.6           lava_1.6.8           stringr_1.4.0        timeDate_3043.102    munsell_0.5.0        gtable_0.3.0        
[31] recipes_0.1.13       htmlwidgets_1.5.2    codetools_0.2-16     crosstalk_1.1.0.1    caret_6.0-86         class_7.3-17        
[37] Rcpp_1.0.5           scales_1.1.1         ipred_0.9-9          jsonlite_1.7.1       digest_0.6.25        stringi_1.4.6       
[43] grid_4.0.2           tools_4.0.2          magrittr_1.5         lazyeval_0.2.2       tibble_3.0.3         tidyr_1.1.0         
[49] crayon_1.3.4         pkgconfig_2.0.3      MASS_7.3-53          ellipsis_0.3.1       Matrix_1.2-18        data.table_1.12.8   
[55] pROC_1.16.2          lubridate_1.7.9      gower_0.2.2          httr_1.4.2           rstudioapi_0.11      iterators_1.0.13    
[61] R6_2.4.1             rpart_4.1-15         nnet_7.3-14          nlme_3.1-149         compiler_4.0.2
```

Comment: Have you tried to isolate which part of the code is taking so long?  I personally would stop it, create the data (and discover if that is the slow down), and then  step by step try to find the issue.

Comment: @Elin: thank you for your reply. yes, it's the plot_ly function for both parts. Are they taking a long time for you as well?

Comment: There are aspects of this code that don't make sense to me (calculating the same thing multiple times, using as.Date() on the same data over and over. Not sure it is necessary to convert to numeric either. Are you sure it is not the cumulate function that is the issue?  https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/957  also try switching to using the original date instead of tmp_date for the x..

Comment: Just looking at those graphs, I do think that you have a lot of data. What if you just try graphing the first 4 months or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the data is not small (535,092 rows following the `accumulate_by` transformation), it should not take hours to generate those plotly graphs. On my machine the whole thing takes under 2 minutes. It appears to leave behind some data that only a restart of R seems to get rid of, so you might want to check the memory footprint.

The code below should be reproducible:

```r
tic <- Sys.time()
suppressPackageStartupMessages(invisible(
  lapply(c("xts", "ggplot2", "dplyr", "plotly"),
    require, character.only = TRUE)))

#create data

#time series 1
date_decision_made <- seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"), by="day") %>% 
  {format(as.Date(.), "%Y/%m/%d")}
property_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,100,10)

final_data <- data.frame(date_decision_made, property_damages_in_dollars) %>% 
  mutate(date_decision_made = as.Date(date_decision_made),
         class = "time_series_1") %>%
  add_count(week = format(date_decision_made, "%W-%y"))

#time series 2
date_decision_made <- seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"), by="day") %>% 
  {format(as.Date(.), "%Y/%m/%d")}
property_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,10,10)

final_data_2 <- data.frame(date_decision_made, property_damages_in_dollars) %>% 
  mutate(date_decision_made = as.Date(date_decision_made),
         class = "time_series_2") %>%
  add_count(week = format(date_decision_made, "%W-%y"))

#combine
data <- rbind(final_data, final_data_2)

#part 1:
data <- data %>%
    mutate(tmp_date = as.numeric(as.Date(date_decision_made, format = "%Y/%m/%d")))

accumulate_by <- function(dat, var) {
    var <- lazyeval::f_eval(var, dat)
    lvls <- plotly:::getLevels(var)
    dats <- lapply(seq_along(lvls), function(x) {
        cbind(dat[var %in% lvls[seq(1, x)], ], frame = lvls[[x]])
    })
    dplyr::bind_rows(dats)
}
data <- data %>% accumulate_by(~tmp_date)
lvls <- plotly:::getLevels(data$tmp_date)

## edit: defined custom tick marks with date labels
myticks <- floor(do.call(seq, as.list(c(range(data$tmp_date),length.out=8))))

fig <- data %>%
    plot_ly(
        x = ~tmp_date, 
        y = ~property_damages_in_dollars,
        split = ~class,
        frame = ~frame,
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines' #, 
        # line = list(simplify = FALSE)
    ) %>%                         # edit: added custom tick labels and text
    layout(xaxis = list(
      tickmode = "array",
      nticks = 8,
      tickvals = myticks, 
      ticktext = data$date_decision_made[myticks]
    ))

myticks <- floor(do.call(seq, as.list(c(range(data$tmp_date),length.out=8))))
fig <- data %>%
    plot_ly(
        x = ~tmp_date, 
        y = ~property_damages_in_dollars,
        text=~date_decision_made,  # edit: added hovertext label
        split = ~class,
        frame = ~frame,
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines'
    ) %>%                          # edit: added custom tick labels and text
    layout(xaxis = list(
      tickmode = "array",
      nticks = 8,
      tickvals = myticks, 
      ticktext = data$date_decision_made[myticks])
    )

fig
```

[image]

```r
#part 2
high_annotations <- list(
    x=unique(data$date_decision_made[data$property_damages_in_dollars == max(data$property_damages_in_dollars)]), 
    y=max(data$property_damages_in_dollars),
    xref='x', yref='y',
    text=paste0('High: $',max(data$property_damages_in_dollars)),
    ax=0, ay=-40
)

low_annotations <- list(
    x=unique(data$date_decision_made[data$property_damages_in_dollars == min(data$property_damages_in_dollars)]), 
    y=min(data$property_damages_in_dollars),
    xref='x', yref='y',
    text=paste0('Low: $',min(data$property_damages_in_dollars)),
    ax=0, ay=40
)

updatemenus <- list(
    list(
        active = -1,
        type= 'buttons',
        buttons = list(
            list(
                label = "time_series_1",
                method = "update",
                args = list(list(visible = c(FALSE, TRUE)),
                            list(title = "series 1",
                                 annotations = list(c(), high_annotations)))),
            list(
                label = "time_series_2",
                method = "update",
                args = list(list(visible = c(TRUE, FALSE)),
                            list(title = "series 2",
                                 annotations = list(low_annotations, c() ))))
            
        )
    )
    
)

fig <- data %>% plot_ly(type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') 
fig <- fig %>% add_lines(x=~date_decision_made,
                         y=~property_damages_in_dollars, name="High",
                         line=list(color="#33CFA5")) 
fig <- fig %>% add_lines(x=~date_decision_made, 
                         y=~property_damages_in_dollars, name="Low",
                         line=list(color="#F06A6A")) 
fig <- fig %>% layout(title = "Apple", showlegend=FALSE,
                      xaxis=list(title="Date"),
                      yaxis=list(title="Price ($)"),
                      updatemenus=updatemenus)

fig
```

[image]

```r
toc <- Sys.time()
toc-tic
#> Time difference of 1.61937 mins
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
other attached packages:
[1] plotly_4.9.2.2 dplyr_1.0.2    ggplot2_3.3.3  xts_0.12.1     zoo_1.8-8
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply! i was spending so much time trying to figure out how to figure out part 2! As for part 1 - do you know how to change the date format from 16.1k to a more recognizable calendar date? i can not thank you enough for your help!

Comment: See edited post - you could add the date in the hover text and add custom x axis labels with the dates. I did not manage to have the frames use the date format, unfortunately.